# tidyverse - Correlations among multiple columns grouped by other column

Tags: r, correlation, tidyverse

I want to get a correlation matrix across several variables in tidyverse. However, I want to do this grouped by another column. E.g. suppose I have a data frame `df` with columns `year` and I want to see correlations across `V1`, `V2`, `V3`by year.

```
year    V1    V2    V3    misc_var
2018    5     6     5     a
2018    4     6     4     b
2018    3     2     3     NA
2013    5     8     2     4
2013    6     3     8     8
2013    4     7     5     NA
```

I tried sth. along the lines of

```
cor_output = df %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  select(V1, V2, V3, year) %>%
  cor(use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
```

However, instead of calculating the correlations from V1 to V3 for each year, it just adds the `year` variable to the correlations.

The desired output should look like (please note the correlations in the output are made up)

```
year    var    V1    V2    V3
2013    V1     1    0.7    0.3
2013    V2     ...    1    ...
...
...
2018    V2    0.6    1    0.7
...
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to use the [`corrr` package](https://github.com/drsimonj/corrr) in conjunction with a `purrr::nest()`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(corrr)

df <- tribble(
    ~year, ~V1, ~V2, ~V3, ~misc_var,
     2018,   5,   6,   5,       "a",
     2018,   4,   6,   4,       "b",
     2018,   3,   2,   3,        NA,
     2013,   5,   8,   2,       "4",
     2013,   6,   3,   8,       "8",
     2013,   4,   7,   5,        NA
    )

df %>%
  select_if(is.numeric) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(
    correlations = map(data, correlate)
  ) %>%
  unnest(correlations)
#> 
#> Correlation method: 'pearson'
#> Missing treated using: 'pairwise.complete.obs'
#> 
#> 
#> Correlation method: 'pearson'
#> Missing treated using: 'pairwise.complete.obs'
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>    year rowname     V1     V2     V3
#>   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1  2018 V1      NA      0.866  1    
#> 2  2018 V2       0.866 NA      0.866
#> 3  2018 V3       1      0.866 NA    
#> 4  2013 V1      NA     -0.756  0.5  
#> 5  2013 V2      -0.756 NA     -0.945
#> 6  2013 V3       0.5   -0.945 NA
```

Alternatively, you could use the more experimental `group_map` or `group_modify` functions from `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
  select_if(is.numeric) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  group_map(~ correlate(.x))      # or group_modify(~ correlate(.x))
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks for your help. I directly tried your alternative solution with using the group_map function, which worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

In general terms:

```
dataframe %>%
  select(grouping_variable, columns) %>%
  group_by(grouping_variable) %>%
  group_modify(~ corrr::correlate(.x))
```

where `columns` may be `c(col_1, col_2, ...)` or `col_1:col_10`